# Unable to authenticate Google Cloud Storage client in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying the following code to access the Google Cloud storage:

```
client = storage.Client(credentials = GoogleCredentials.from_stream(<path-to-service-account-json>))
```

Throws this error:

```
ValueError: This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/google-cloud-auth.html for help on authentication with this library.
```

I'm able to authenticate `discovery.build` service using the same credentials(obtained using `GoogleCredentials.from_stream()`), but for some reason storage.Client fails to use the provided credentials.

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Got it to work with the following code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(<path-to-service-account-json>)
```

Not sure why there are different way to authenticate the discovery API and the storage and other client APIs.

Comment: Individual APIs use the pattern `Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json')`.  The `GoogleCredentials` class is part of an older library. The way to explicitly use a Credentials object with `google-auth-library-python` would look more like `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/path/to/keyfile.json')`.  More docs on that method: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

You're probably doing discovery with that older Python API, which does use GoogleCredentials. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you, can't find any useful docs for this client library so your post is extra helpful.