# How authenticate with gcloud credentials an Dialogflow API

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, service-accounts

I have a Node JS app that make requests to a Dialogflow agent. I actually use a temporally token based request, but how can i change this to do it through google service credentials? (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). I have a credencial created (with billing added), and the service_account json file.

I would like to use the Dialogflow package in node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) but i don't underestand how to use it with the json file.

```
const projectId = 'ENTER_PROJECT_ID_HERE'; 
const sessionId = 'quickstart-session-id';
const query = 'hello';
const languageCode = 'en-US';

// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
```

The example of the package use Project ID and Session ID, but not with a json file like the example of the google services (or using big query like [How to authenticate with gcloud big query using a json credentials file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529331/how-to-authenticate-with-gcloud-big-query-using-a-json-credentials-file)). Anyway, where can i get this project and session id?

Please, if someone can help me or guide how to do this in a better way?. Thanks

Comment: I have done that with a service account but using Java/kotlin if that would help you then i could share the code.. im sure there is something similar for JS

Comment: Yes, sure please!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you have to create a service account and download a **.JSON** format file of credentials on your local system. 
Now, there are three ways to use that credentials for authentication/authorisation in dialogflow library.

- **Method 1**

  Create a environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** and it's value should be the absolute path of that JSON credentials file.By this method, google library will implicitly loads the file and use that credentials for authentication. We don't need to do anything inside our code relating to this credentials file.

  ```
  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<absolute-path-of-json-file>" # for UNIX,LINUX
  # then run your code, google library will pick credentials file and loads it automatically
  ```
- **Method 2**

  Assume, you know the absolute path of your JSON file and put that as value in below snippet of **credentials_file_path** variable.

  ```js
  // You can find your project ID in your Dialogflow agent settings
  const projectId = '<project-id-here>';
  const sessionId = '<put-chat-session-id-here>'; 
  // const sessionid = 'fa2d5904-a751-40e0-a878-d622fa8d65d9'
  const query = 'hi';
  const languageCode = 'en-US';
  const credentials_file_path = '<absolute-file-path-of-JSON-file>';

  // Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    projectId,
    keyFilename: credentials_file_path,
  });
  ```
- **Method 3**

  You can note down the *project_id*, *client_email* and *private_key* from the JSON, use them in your code for authentication explicitly.

```js
// You can find your project ID in your Dialogflow agent settings
const projectId = '<project-id-here>';
const sessionId = '<put-chat-session-id-here>';
// const sessionid = 'fa2d5904-a751-40e0-a878-d622fa8d65d9'
const query = 'hi';
const languageCode = 'en-US';
const credentials = {
  client_email: '<client-email-here>',
  private_key:
    '<private-key-here>',
};
// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  projectId,
  credentials,
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, but from where i get the "const sessionId = 'fa2d5904-a751-40e0-a878-d622fa8d65d9';"?. The json file come with this values: type, project_id, private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, and client_x509_cert_url.

Comment: @Sebastián session id you can set any arbitrary value which you want to distinguish a user chat. From json file, you only consider project_id, client_email and private_key only, if you are using method 3

Comment: how to test and run that method 3 ? should we do http request ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with a service account code sample is in kotlin and definitely can be translated into the node.js sdk

```
    val credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials
            .fromStream(Classes.getResourceAsStream([YOUR JSON CONFIG FILE GOES HERE])))
    val sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build()
    sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings)
```

You can get the service account from Dialogflow settings click on the service account links and then create a json config file there in ur cloud console.