# Can't access DialogFlow API via node

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to access Google's DialogFlow API using nodeJS and get the following error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials.
```

It finds the API key fine and loads the client, but wont run the query under localhost. It seems to be looking for the default credentials, but I am specifying ones from the service account.

```
    const {SessionsClient} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow').v2;
    const dfKey=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./assets/keys/dialogflow.json"));
    const dfClient=new dialogflow.SessionsClient({ private_key:dfKey.private_key,client_email:dfKey.client_email });

    const detectIntent = async (queryText, sessionId="123456789") => {
        let sessionPath=dfClient.projectAgentSessionPath(dfKey.project_id, sessionId);
        let request = { session: sessionPath, queryInput:{ text: {  text: queryText, languageCode: "en" } } };
        const responses = await dfClient.detectIntent(request);
        console.log(responses);
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        console.log(result);
        return { response: result.fulfillmentText };
    }
    
detectIntent("How are you")
```

It finds the API key fine and loads the client, but wont run the query under localhost. It seems to be looking for the default credentials, but I am specifying ones from the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not loading the default credential
using the GCP API I set in my .env something like

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./google_key/creds.json
```

Hope it helps

Ok looking at an other solution

1. method GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDETIALS
2. 

```
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
      projectId,
      keyFilename: credentials_file_path,
    });
```

this is the reference
[How authenticate with gcloud credentials an Dialogflow API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355556/how-authenticate-with-gcloud-credentials-an-dialogflow-api)

Comment: Thanks,but that didn;t work.

Comment: try to console.log (dfKey)

Comment: dfkey looks good

Comment: This worked!

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
      projectId,
      keyFilename: credentials_file_path,
    });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with node, but in the few prototypes I dealt with I needed to explicitly declare the auth keys instead of simply pointing the client instantiation to the key.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/blob/master/twilio/server.js). maybe it could be a good boilerplate code to build yours upon.

Just out of curiosity - Have you double checked if the service account you are using has the proper dialogflow roles assigned (ie. `Dialogflow API Client`)?